# Gaussian elimination to solve half of vector values while the other values are varied

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to solve a linear system using Gaussian elimination where a half of variables are varied and I need to solve the system to adapt the other half of variables in order to get the system correct.

**For example**, I have the the system $W*x = y$ where $W$ is known matrix and $y$ is known too, and half of the vector $x$ is varied, it mean it can by any random values,  what I need is to set the other half of the vector $d$ to get the correct equality of the system.

Example:

I have the system as following:

[image]

Suppose that the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are varied and can be any random values,  for example $1$ and $-1$, respectively. Therefore the above equation will be written as below:

[image]

I need to solve $k_1$ and $k_2$ to get the above equation right. Normally, as I know, we can do it as following:

[image]

Which gives:

[image]

Finally, that can be written as:

[image]

So, I cannot solve $k_1$ and $k_2$ in that case to solve the system in the first equation!!

My question, Is it possible to solve the variables $k_1$ and $k_2$ to make the equality right ?If not,  is there any other algorithm we can use it instead of Gaussian elimination to solve it?

**Another example**

$W = [0.5+0.5i , 0.5-0.5i; 0.5-0.5i, 0.5+0.5i]$,  and multiplied by a vector $[0.7; k]$; the resultant vector should be $y = [1; -1]$.   I think the value of $k$ which makes the multiplication correct should exist, is that right ? but how can we find it mathematically?

Comment: You have more equations than unknowns so that your system is over-determined. In general there is no consistent solution for the unknowns (different sets of equations will give different 'solutions'). You could find an approximate solution for your k values by solving the normal equation. This gives the closest combination of the columns of your matrix to the right hand vector $b$. Look up over-determined, consistent and normal equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\m#1{ \left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right] }$The full system is
$$Aw=b$$
Without doing any math, notice that the columns of $A$ are all orthogonal to one another (i.e. it has full rank), while $b$ is equal to the ${\tt2}^{nd}$ column and therefore the unique solution vector for the full system is the ${\tt2}^{nd}$ basis vector, i.e.
$$w = \m{0\\1\\0\\0}$$
Writing the system in partitioned form
$$
\big[V\quad W\big]\,\m{x\\k} = b
\qquad\implies\quad Wk = (b-Vx)
$$
does not change the solution. But choosing $x\ne\m{0\\1}$ makes the system *inconsistent*.

The best one can do in such circumstances is a least-squares solution
$$k = W^+(b-Vx) + (I-W^+W)y$$
where $W^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse and $y$ is an arbitrary vector.

For the given matrix $\quad W^+=\frac 14W^T$

Comment: what is $y$ in your last equation, I mean how can I initialize it? and what's the dimension of $I$ , it $(2,4), right ?$  Yes in my case, the columns and rows or matrix $A$ are always orthogonal and full rank

Comment: The vector $y$ is completely arbitrary, but zero is a common choice. The dimensions of the various variables: $(k,x,y)$ are $2\times 1,\;$ $(V,W)$ are $4\times 2,\;$ $(I,\,W^+W)$ are $2\times 2,\;$ $(b,w)$ are $4\times 1,\;$ and $A$ is $4\times 4$.

Comment: I supposed $y = 0$, then when following your steps to solve the example I provided above, and find $k$, the multiplication of $A*[x;k]$  (In my case $W*[x;k]$) doesn't give $b$, it gives different vector.   I will add another easier example too for clarification

Comment: If you choose $x\ne[0\;1]^T$ you can **never** recover $b$ because the system is inconsistent. If you choose $x=[0\;1]^T$ then $k=[0\;0]^T$ recovers $b$ and this is the **only** solution that will recover $b$.